# .htaccess mod_rewrite to clean up variable urls

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm sure there is something out there to answer my question, but I cannot find it.

In short: I want to use .htaccess and mod_rewrite to clean up my urls.

Currently I have 3 possible variables.

c for category, m for manufacturer, and p for page.

if there is just c, it will display all the possible manufacturers under that category. If there is a c and an m it will display the first 30 items of that manufacturer under that category, and then if there is more then 30 you can go to the next page, p, and on.

This is what I'm trying to accomplish:

index.php?c=Category1 turns into /Category1
index.php?c=Category1&m=Manufacturer1 turns into /Category1/Manufacturer1
index.php?c=Category1&m=Manufacturer1&p=1 turns into /Category1/Manufacturer1/page/1 (or Category1/Manufacturer1/1/)

I have tried a couple things I've found but I can't translate them to my scenario.

I've tried

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php?p=$1
```

and

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1
```

however

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1
```

works but that is not what I want for the first 2 parameters.

What rules do I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either make 3 separate rules or if you don't care about blank `$_GET` variables, use optional groupings:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?c=$1&m=$2&p=$3 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?c=$1&m=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?c=$1 [L]
```

or

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(?:/([^/]+)|)(?:/([^/]+)|)/?$ /index.php?c=$1&m=$2&p=$3 [L]
```

Comment: Both of those send me to my 404 page.

Comment: I figured out the problem. the /before index.php was cauing the problem so my rules look like
    RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?c=$1 [L]